# Cannot locate project.cmake in my esp-idf framework

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, platformio

I cxannot build any of my ESP projects. I am using VSCode with platformio.

I keep getting the following error:

***CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (include):
include could not find load file:
C:\XXXXXX\XXXXXX.platformio\packages\framework espidf/tools/cmake/project.cmake

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.***

I checked the above directory and I see I do not have this:

[image]

I tried deleting the framework-espidf folder and building it again. The framework di download again however I still get the same error.

I do not know what else to do, can someone assit?

Comment: Your file structure doesn't seems to be correctly installed for esp-idf, maybe you should check the [documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/frameworks/espidf.html) first.

Comment: @hcheung I am so overusing platformio. I am downloading the esp-IDF extension on vscode and uisng that. Platformio just complicates things!